# python difference between @classmethod and @somemethod("some-parameter")

Tags: python, decorator

I'm starting out in Python and have a base level understanding but still learning the architecture.

consider this method and the decorator (I think) above it:

[image]

I see documentation on a `@classmethod` [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#classmethod), but this appears to be something else.

**My question**: What is it, where is the documentation on it, and how does it work?

Comment: I hate that "How to make function decorators and chain them together?" is the title of our canonical explaining what a decorator is and how they work, but that's how it is. Any other title wouldn't be right for the question that was actually asked.

Comment: That said: you have multiple gold badges and appear to have been using the site somewhat regularly for multiple years, so I shouldn't have to remind you to [research](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/) questions before asking. "the decorator (I think)" Okay; so did you try putting `python what is a decorator` into a search engine? "where is the documentation on it" Did you try putting `mocks_exception_handler decorator documentation` (possibly also including the name of whatever third-party library it is that you're using) into a search engine?

Comment: For that matter, even if you have no idea about the name, something as simple as `python at sign before function` [gets useful results](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=python+at+sign+before+function).